# ESP8266 not running when connected to 3V3

Tags: esp8266

I have a simple code that uses a tactile button and ESP8266.  I have one wire going from GND to one leg and one wire going from D3 to the other leg.  Works perfectly.  When I start it up, I have write statements in setup() which show that it is starting up and working.

I wanted to switch to a Touch Sensor.  I added a wire from one of the 3V3 to the VCC of the sensor.  If I do this while the program is running it seems to work... (it recognizes when I touch the sensor).  However, if I reset the ESP, then it no longer runs.  I see nothing in the serial window.

I tried to narrow the problem down and here's where I'm at...

1. The ESP is connected via USB to the computer so I can look at the console window to track how it's running.
2. I have a wire connected to D3 and GND (but the ends aren't connected to anything).  I reset the ESP and I see in the console window that it is printing out the expected print statements in setup().
3. I add a wire to 3V3 (it is not connected to anything).  I reset the ESP and now no print statements are in the console window - so I believe it is not running.

Why?  I thought 3V3 was to connect to sensors to power them.  Not input to the ESP.  So what am I missing?

RESOLVED:  I randomly picked the wrong GPIO to use... I switched to D1 and it now works ok.